# Attribute tag is not working in front-end side

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am trying to return an attribute tag from controller to front-end side but attribute link and class is not working.

[Click here (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNjLj.png)

### Controller Side

```
public function religionlist(){

    $view_data = DB::select("SELECT 
                                id,religion
                            FROM 
                                hrm_religion");


    $religion_data   = collect($view_data);

    return DataTables::of($religion_data)
    ->addColumn('Link', function ($religion_data) {
       return 
       ' <a href="'. url('/religion') . '/' . 
       Crypt::encrypt($religion_data->id) . 
       '/edit' .'"' . 
       'class="btn btn-success btn-sm block btn-flat"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit-sign" id="customer-confrimed"></i> confirm</a>';        
     })
    ->editColumn('id', '{{$id}}')
    ->setRowId('id')
    ->make(true);


}
```

### Front-end Side

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#list_table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "paging": true,
    "ajax": "{{URL::to('/')}}/religion_list",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "religion" },
        { "data": "Link", name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'asc']]
  });

});
```

Comment: what html you are getting  finally?

Comment: already added image , please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace your return statement with below one?

```
return '<a href="'.url('religion').'/'.Crypt::encrypt($religion_data->id).'/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm block btn-flat"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit-sign" id="customer-confrimed"></i> Confirm</a>'
```

Please review this below link

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1305

just add `->rawColumns(['Link'])` in your code.

```
 return DataTables::of($religion_data)
    ->addColumn('Link', function ($religion_data) {
       return 
       ' <a href="'. url('/religion') . '/' . 
       Crypt::encrypt($religion_data->id) . 
       '/edit' .'"' . 
       'class="btn btn-success btn-sm block btn-flat"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit-sign" id="customer-confrimed"></i> confirm</a>';        
     })
    ->editColumn('id', '{{$id}}')
    ->setRowId('id')
    ->rawColumns(['Link'])
    ->make(true);
```

Comment: @AbdullahNoman You need to pass raw column to get html in fornt end.
->rawColumns(['Link'])

Comment: after adding this it is working. Thanks.@jigar halani